# Stricter return type for object literal in Typescript

Tags: typescript, type-inference

In this code

```
const s = "myKey" as const;
const myF = () => ({
  [s]: 0,
});
```

the type of `myF` is `function myF(): {[p: string]: number, myKey: number}`

where return type is `{[p: string]: number, myKey: number}`

As you can see, unwanted `[p: string]: number` leaks here.

How do I make my return type an expected {myKey: number} without explicit type annotation?

I don't want to go into explicit annotation just yet since I got some types with a LOT of fields.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using? When i paste your code into the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBBMF4YCIC2BPA0gU3cmAhvKJFANwCwAUCdDBgGKIwAUAlIgHysDe1MMANoQAugC4YABgA01AL5tKVarVhRsdJI3ZLaIADbYAdPpABzFuuhGMOdIpXgIB46YtWoRgGYgQioA), i see `myF` having type `() => { myKey: number }` for most versions of typescript

Comment: Is your actual code more complex than the above? I would guess you might have a situation where the equivalent of `s` in your real code is typed as `string` instead of as a specific string literal type and is causing what you see.

Comment: Typescript playground shows the expected behavior. Maybe the issue is I'm checking in IDEA (Ultimate / Webstorm, doesn't matter) type inspector. Maybe it's IDEA issue indeed.

Comment: > is your actual code more complex than the above?  It is but I simplified it into this example.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior of TypeScript. It always evaluates computed property to string.

You can write custom helper to create objects:

```js
const s = "myKey";

const record = <Prop extends PropertyKey, Value>(prop: Prop, value: Value) => 
  ({ [prop]: value }) as Record<Prop, Value>

// const myF: () => Record<"myKey", number>
const myF = () => record(s, 42)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBMF4YCIC2BPA0gU3cg3AFCGiSwBO2o5AJojADwAK5IADjNgB5TZg3wW7bOShZcAGhgA1AIYAbAK7YAfAAo2rNgC4YQtlIBuC5brlLsASkQqYhGDDUBvGAG1N7ALq7jFmAF9rWXgAJSoQWmYtKXNlFWJSaBgMADF6NWsEW0pqGjUIKQAWACZLIA)

You don't need to use `as const`

Be aware that this solution has a drawback.

```js
const drawback = record<'myKey' & { hello?: 'world' }, 42>('myKey', 42).myKey // error
```

Hence, you better to avoid using explicit generics for this function

Comment: > This is the default behavior of TypeScript. It always evaluates computed property to string.

```
const prop = "PROP";

const myO = {
  [prop]: 1
};
```

would have type `{PROP: number}`

Comment: I guess that's what I'm trying to achieve - have the same behavior with function return. My real type is a bit more than that - it has several props with different types.

Comment: @IgorLoskutov please share your real example